# spring importing module on runtime ignored in bean

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

Hi I have a 2 projects A and B where B is dependant of A.

So i put in maven the dependency.
The problem is on compilation everything is ok, but whenever i run it on tomcat i get

> CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.example.A.user.UserDetailsServiceImpl] for bean with name 'userService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sec-context.xml]

Even thouh the bean is correct, the project A is well referenced in project B and Maven is well updated.

The context's component scan is `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />` so the problem is not there.

I'm having the same problem with `Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource'` even though i added to pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

[edited based on the answers below]

[image]

The problem is that in xml, the autocomplete is working, and navigating from it to the class, actually takes me to the right class.

What are the steps to check what's wrong (I'm working on intelliJ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are pulling wrong dependency, you need `commons-dbcp2`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added this dependency, and still having the same error, actually how can i check the jars that has been added to the project, to know that maven imported correctly all the libraries?. I mean how can I "debug" the issue

Answer (score 0):

I would say thats a simple typo / inconsistency.

ClassNotFound: com.exmable...

And you scan for: com.example...

Comment: this was a typo in the question, the name is right in the project :)

Comment: Too bad. Would have been easy :)